# Reading metadata in a Haxe macro

Tags: macros, haxe

I would like to know how to read metadata from a class (and its methods) in a macro.

I tried to modify [this example](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-metadata.html).
I added `:` to see if metadata without them is only available in generated code, but nothing.. I have an empty result in all three cases.. Any ideas?

```
@:author("Nicolas")
@debug
class MyClass {
    @:range(1, 8)
    var value:Int;

    @broken
    @:noCompletion
    static function method() { }
}

class Boot {
    static public function main() {
        test();
    }

    macro public static function test() {
        trace(haxe.rtti.Meta.getType(MyClass)); // { author : ["Nicolas"], debug : null }
        trace(haxe.rtti.Meta.getFields(MyClass).value.range); // [1,8]
        trace(haxe.rtti.Meta.getStatics(MyClass).method); // { broken: null }
        return haxe.macro.Context.makeExpr({}, haxe.macro.Context.currentPos());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to access the types from a macro, you need to use the [`haxe.macro.*`](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/index.html) API rather than accessing `haxe.rtti`. The following example will trace both `debug` and `author`, which are the metadata applied to `MyClass`:

```
class Boot
{
  macro public static function test()
  {
    switch (haxe.macro.Context.getType("MyClass"))
    {
      case TInst(cl,_):
        trace(cl.get().meta.get());
      case _:
    }
  }
}
```

In order to get class field metadata, you must go through all fields from `cl.get().fields.get()`.

See [`Context.getType()`](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Context.html#getType), [`ClassType`](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/ClassType.html) and [`MetaAccess`](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/MetaAccess.html).

Comment: Pretty new to this, but could you elaborate where the `cl` and `_` comes from? (ex: in `case TInst(cl,_):` and `case _:`)

Comment: @bigp have a look at the pattern matching documentation ( at http://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching.html )